# How to move in and out of wallets cheaply and fast?

Tags: wallet, trezor, ledger-hardware-wallet, money-transfer

So... Trezor has ridiculously high fee for "normal" speed of transferring money. If I select cheapest transfer version, it takes more than 2 days.

Is there a way to transfer money between a crypto-wallet (such as Trezor Wallet) and an exchange (such as GDAX) quickly AND cheaply?

Otherwise this safe storage seems like a big limiting step in quick-response trading.

Comment: The quicker you want, the more in miner's fee you need to spend. GDAX is an exception though, since they don't charge fees for sending.

Comment: You shouldn't be using gdax btw. They refuse to support segwit addresses which would cut your fees in half or more. Try ShapeShift, Bitstamp, or CryptoPay. Here's more info that will be kept updated: https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_adoption/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the amount of the transaction fee affect the priority of a transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/does-the-amount-of-the-transaction-fee-affect-the-priority-of-a-transaction)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pay the fee necessary to get your transaction on the blockchain in the timeframe you're comfortable with.

If you want to transact cheaper and faster than Bitcoin can allow onchain, the Lightning Network (LN) will allow you to do this. Once you have a LN channel open, you can send to anyone (including an exchange) instantly for a very low fee. Exchanges like gdax won't be needed for crypto-to-crypto exchanges as soon as atomic swaps become available on more coins. Once that happens, you won't need a 3rd party to exchange cryptocurrencies (tho you'll still need them for dealing with fiat).

For more info on the Lightning Network, see the "So you wanna understand the lightning network" section here: https://governology.wordpress.com/2017/07/21/so-you-wanna-understand-bitcoin-part-2/